# transpose mdx results => values are lost

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube

I created an MDX query with some named calculus (using 'WITH' keyword).
The last part is:

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[PCT0p02],[Measures].[PCT0p2],[Measures].[PCT0p5],[Measures].[PCT0p8],[Measures].[PCT0p98]} on 0
FROM [My cube]
```

It gives me this:

[image: the result]

I would like to transpose these results in order to feed an SSRS report.

But write

```
SELECT
{     } on 0,
{  [Measures].[PCT0p02],[Measures].[PCT0p2],[Measures].[PCT0p5],[Measures].[PCT0p8],[Measures]. 
[PCT0p98] } on 1
FROM [My cube]
```

returns

[image: bad result]

Please tell me how not to lose the value

EDIT:
The answer given works, but when I try to use it in SSRS I get an error: it complains that a measure is needed in the columns axis:
[image: problem in SSRS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have something in your 0 axis to satisfy MDX, however you dont want it to modify your result. **Defaultmember** will help with this.. Example lets say you have a dimension **DimA**, within DimA you have an attribute **AT1**, then your query will be

```
SELECT
{  DimA.AT1.Defaultmember   } on 0,
{  [Measures].[PCT0p02],[Measures].[PCT0p2],[Measures].[PCT0p5],[Measures].[PCT0p8],[Measures]. 
[PCT0p98] } on 1
FROM [My cube]
```